document is not defined in Astro projext even after adding client:load directive
I had a basic html and css with with  vanila javascript which works with keyboard interactions and now transformed to astro but getiing error

document not defined and sugegsted to use client:only

I understand that Astro use SSR so it does not hyderate, but when apply client:load it gives the same error
here is sample code
Panel.astro
---
import "assets/styles/panel.css";

import { updatePanel} from "@/components/panel";

---
 <label class="vertical" for="vertical">
      <input type="radio" class="orientation" name="orientation" id="vertical" value="X">
 </label>

components/panle.ts
const orientationPanel = document.querySelectorAll(".orientation");
const panel = document.querySelector(".panel");

const updatePanel = (num = 0) => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("panel__cell");
    div.textContent = String.fromCodePoint(65 + i); // A to Z
    fragment.appendChild(div);
  }
  panel.innerHTML = "";
  panel.appendChild(fragment);
};

const onChangePanel = (e: any) => {
  changePanel(e.target.value);
  updatePanel(Number(e.keyCode));
};

orientationPanel?.addEventListener("change", onChangePanel);

it throw error as below

[ERROR] document is not defined   Hint:
Browser APIs are not available on the server.
If the code is in a framework component, try to access these objects after rendering using lifecycle methods
or use a client:only directive to make the component exclusively run on the client

.
so tries to add client:only which has below code
Navigation.astro
---
import "@/assets/styles/nav.css";
---
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav--list">
    <a class="link list--item" href="/panel" client:load><span>Panel</span></a>
  </div>
</nav>

sidenote: when use client:load then  throw typescript error on the element
Type '{ children: any; class: string; href: string; "client:load": true; }' is not assignable to type 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'.
  Property 'client:load' does not exist on type 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'.ts(2322)

it might be because using <a> so create an Astro component
Link.astro
---
const { href, name } = Astro.props

---

<a class="link list--item" href={href}><span>{name}</span></a>

and use it in Navigation.astro
<Link href="panel" name="panel" client:load/>

but still throwing same

document is not defined
Hint:
Browser APIs are not available on the server.

update
now stopped importing panel.ts  then throw error

You are attempting to render , but Link is an
Astro component. Astro components do not render in the client and
should not have a hydration directive. Please use a framework
component for client rendering.



I had recently a similar issue with cally.
My problem was that I had been trying to import cally from the Astro script side like this:
---
import "cally";
import { getISO639FromLang, getLangFromUrl } from '@/i18n/utils';

const lang = getLangFromUrl(Astro.url);
---

<div>...</div>

Astro was throwing errors because this piece of code is being executed outside the actual browser. When you try to use any code that accesses document or window, it will crash.
Try moving the code that accesses the document object to the script side like this:
---
import { getISO639FromLang, getLangFromUrl } from '@/i18n/utils';

const lang = getLangFromUrl(Astro.url);
---

<div>...</div>

<script>
import "cally";
</script>


alonng with this; do we need to mention client:load directive also

In my case was not required since I did not use any framework, but pick your weapon
